# how to access database object from another server in client sid

Tags: javascript, json, django

I have working on project that using Django.I have render some data as json format with httpresponse in url like this "1.1.1.1:8080/data". and get data with javascript and AJAX in client side, I should mention that this server have no access to intenet and it work in internal network of our company. this work prefect. but another server like 'example.com' want to render my html and i manage it, this work well but the data  "1.1.1.1:8080/data" do not load and return error on pinging.
so is there any solution to make access my django app load data on 'example.com'.
best regarads

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: error 500 , 'example.com' can not access '1.1.1.1:8080/data'